# Is the Python 3 input() function safe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, input

Does the `input()` function have security issues?

For your information, I am using python 3.x currently.

Comment: Just as much as any other function which accepts user input would.

Comment: well it always `return`s a string unlike Py 2 `input`, is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No.

It just takes whatever is passed in and returns it in string-form (at least on Python-3.x). What you do with that string could be unsafe though. The most prominent example for an unsafe processing of `input` is `eval` - don't use that function on the string returned from `input` - ever!

However it's unsafe for security related informations because what you entered is visible in the prompt ([shoulder surfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoulder_surfing_(computer_security)))! If you want to hide it, for example for password prompts, you should use the [built-in `getpass` module](https://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html) instead (or a similar library).